# Formal proof for P → Q ≡ ¬P ∨ Q in Fitch

Tags: logic, proof, fitch-proofs

I'm trying to construct a formal proof for 'P → Q ≡ ¬P ∨ Q' in Fitch. I know this is true, but how do I prove it?

Comment: Would you consider a truth table as a proof?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a formal proof in Fitch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it:

[image]

fairly straight forward actually

Answer (score 1):

Given p ⇒ q, use the Fitch System to prove ¬p ∨ q.

```
1.  p => q            Premise
2.    ~(~p | q)       Assumption
3.      ~p            Assumption
4.      ~p | q        Or Introduction: 3
5.    ~p => ~p | q    Implication Introduction: 3, 4
6.     ~p             Assumption
7.     ~(~p | q)      Reiteration: 2
8.    ~p => ~(~p | q) Implication Introduction: 6, 7
9.    ~~p             Negation Introduction: 5, 8
10.   p               Negation Elimination: 9
11.   q               Implication Elimination: 1, 10
12.   ~p | q          Or Introduction: 11
13. ~(~p | q) => ~p | q        Implication Introduction: 2, 12
14.  ~(~p | q)                 Assumption
15. ~(~p | q) => ~(~p | q)     Implication Introduction: 14, 14
16. ~~(~p | q)                 Negation Introduction: 13, 15
17. ~p | q                     Negation Elimination: 16
```

Goal      ~p | q    Complete